# Setting up custom RMM forward setting at the time of send

Tags: api, marketing-cloud, ampscript

is it possible to set a custom RMM forward from name and email address for a triggered send? either if it's by the API or with AMPscript?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome Pato  to SFSE!

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the [`MessageDefinitionSend`](https://code.exacttarget.com/api/messaging-messagedefinitionsends-send) route and set the `from.name` object:

```
{
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "Code@"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "Region": "West",
                "City": "Indianapolis",
                "State": "IN"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Kelly, the thing is that I need set the RMM settings for a triggered send at the time of send for each individual triggered. So I wasn't sure if this can be done with AMPScript or the API.

Comment: Not sure setting up RMM for each individual send is a good idea really.  What's the reasoning for separate management? I'm also assuming individual sender profile's are not useful? To set the triggered send's RMM everytime new would probably require a restart on the TSD.

Comment: That's a good point. The goal is to be able to have 1 unique Triggered Send with one Sender Profile where the client can change the replyto email address and replyto name (just like you can do now with the From Name and Email). 
I proposed having multiple TS with the corresponding sender profile but I figured I'd ask if we could do something similar to the From Name and Email.

Comment: I'll update the answer, but use the REST message send route. That allows you to change the from name.

Comment: cool , I'll assume then that the replyTo information can't be set with the API. Thanks!